# При парсинге html Beautiful Soup выдает пустой список

Tags: python, парсер, list, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://store.steampowered.com/specials/'
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
games = soup.find_all('div', class_='salepreviewwidgets_StoreSalePriceBox_Wh0L8')
print(games)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для парсинга сайтов с динамически подгружаемым контентом можно использовать следующее решение, вот пример рабочего кода для Вашего случая с использованием selenium:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = f'https://store.steampowered.com/specials/'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
}

def get_result(url, headers):

    chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.binary_location = "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    executable_path=".../chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver") # the path to your chromedriver
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)  # You can wait until the page loads, but it's easier to wait 10 seconds, they will be enough with a margin
    html = driver.page_source
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    games = soup.find_all('div', 
    class_='salepreviewwidgets_StoreSaleDiscountedPriceCtn_3GLeQ')
    for game in games:
        price_original = f'Цена без скидки: {game.find("div", 
        class_="salepreviewwidgets_StoreOriginalPrice_1EKGZ").text}'
        price_sale = f'Цена после скидки: {game.find("div", 
        class_="salepreviewwidgets_StoreSalePriceBox_Wh0L8").text}'
        print(price_original)
        print(price_sale)


def main():
    get_result(url=url, headers=headers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Результат:

```
Цена без скидки: 385 руб
Цена после скидки: 38,50 руб
Цена без скидки: 999 руб
Цена после скидки: 199 руб
Цена без скидки: 419 руб
Цена после скидки: 335 руб
Цена без скидки: 1999 руб
Цена после скидки: 1319 руб
....
```

Comment: "Для парсинга сайтов с динамически подгружаемым контентом нужно использовать что либо на подобии selenium.", а как же requests?

Comment: Согласен, можно и requests. Изменил ответ.